# Error in regex hive

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive

While creating a table in Hive:

> create table lg(ip string, month string, gt string, id int, id1 int)
>   row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
>   with serdeproperties(
>   "input.regex" = "  ([^ ]) - - [([^]]+)] \"([^ ]) ([^ ]) ([^ \"])\")?"
>   "output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5$s"
>   )
>   stored as textfile;

I get an error:

```
ERROR:FAILED: Parse Error: line 5:0 mismatched input '"output.format.string"' expecting ) near '"  ([^ ]) - - [([^]]+)] \"([^ ]) ([^ ]) ([^ \"])\")?"' in table properties

TABLE DATA: 10.22.17.186 - - [15/Aug/2009:15:50:35 -0700] "GET /assets/css/the-associates.css HTTP/1.1" 200 15779
```

Answer (score 0):

try follow input regex ?

```
'input.regex' = ' ([^ ]) - - [([^]]+)] "([^ ]) ([^ ]) ([^ "])")?'
```

Comment: i have solved problem by "([^*]) ([^*]) ([^*]) \\[([^]]+)\\] ([^ \"]*|\"[^\"]*\") ([^*]) ([^*])?"but when i am writing query as select * from lg it is showing all nulls.

Comment: try "([^*]) ([^*]) ([^*]) \\[([^\\]]+)\\] ([^ \"]*|\"[^\"]*\") ([^*]) ([^*])?"